# Example of S-Box truth table in AES

Tags: aes, s-boxes

I'm trying to understand some cryptographic properties of the s-box so I can have my own code. Example of balanced properties I read in [this document](https://thesis.cust.edu.pk/UploadedFiles/Fatima%20Ishfaq-MMT153016.pdf)  that they say

> A boolean function S : $ GF(2^n) $ $ \to $ $ GF(2) $ is called balanced if the output
> set contains equal number of ones and zeros in the corresponding truth table.
>
> **Example 2.2.3** We provide a comparison of balanced and unbalanced functions. Consider two boolean functions, XOR and AND defined as:
>
> $ S_1 = \oplus : GF(2^n)  \to  GF(2)  $
>
> $ S_2 = \cdot : GF(2^n)  \to  GF(2)  $
>
> They define following truth table for two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$.
>
> [image]
>
> Table 2.12: Truth Table of XOR, AND functions
>
> Third column has equal number of zeros and ones representing “XOR” function which is balanced while fourth column presents “AND” function which
> is not balanced.

With the above example, I can easily understand. But for the S-box in AES I still can't imagine how it will be represented. Could you please help me get an example of S-Box truth table in AES?

Comment: The AES S-box table is represented in [FIPS 197](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf#page=20), figure 7 on bottom of page marked 6, with explanation above. If anything is unclear, what?

Comment: @fgrieu I know s-box is a mapping of boolean function. So how to make the truth table of s-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how is the S-box in AES represented ?

[FIPS 197 Figure 7](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf#page=20) is the truth table of the AES S-box, stated in hexadecimal for compactness. That's the most usual and arguably most convenient representation. For example, for input $\mathtt{53_h}$, the output is determined by the intersection of the row with index ‘5’ and the column with index ‘3’. This results in the output having value $\mathtt{ed_h}$.

[image: FIPS 197 Figure 7]

If we wanted a representation more similar to the representation in the question, that is in binary rather than hexadecimal, that would be a table with 8 input columns on the left (thus $2^8=256$ lines to cover all the cases, e.g. by increasing value per [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) binary), and 8 output columns (obtained by converting to binary per same convention the content of table 7 in reading order) on the right. That could go
$$\begin{array}{cccccccc|cccccccc}
i_7&i_6&i_5&i_4&i_3&i_2&i_1&i_0&o_7&o_6&o_5&o_4&o_3&o_2&o_1&o_0\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&1&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&0&1&1&1&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&1&0\\
.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&1&0&1&1&1&0&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&0\\
\end{array}$$

---

> How to make the truth table of S-box?

If we want to build table 7 or it's binary equivalent above from scratch (rather than using the values in table 7 given in the standard), we can apply the definition of the S-box as stated in [FIPS 197 section 5.1.1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf#page=19). We can merely apply for each of the $2^8=256$ entries:

1. inversion in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$ per the stated convention/reduction polynomial, except for input $\mathtt{00_h}$ left unchanged
2. apply a linear transformation where each of 8 output bits $i$ is computed as $b_i\oplus b_{i+4\bmod8}\oplus b_{i+5\bmod8}\oplus b_{i+6\bmod8}\oplus b_{i+7\bmod8}$
3. XOR with the constant $\mathtt{63_h}$

Optimizations are possible, including using that for all $k$, the inverse of $\mathtt{02_h}^k$ is $\mathtt{8d_h}^k$, which allows to compute the inverses simply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that "8 input columns on the left and 8 output columns". I seem to have understood what that means.